# Construct a big json response from multiple pyodbc database query result

Tags: python, json, pyodbc

I'm constructing json response from data in database using pyodbc. Some of the fields are direct mapping from table column, whereas some of them have to be in list, dict format.

Table structure and data looks like below

custid | custacct | invoiceperiod | amtdue | duedate | charges | balance |col8|col9|col10
abc | 101 | 20190801 | 12 | somedate | 2 | 10 |col8|col9|col10
abc | 101 | 20190701 | 13 | somedate | 3 | 13 |col8|col9|col10
abc | 101 | 20190601 | 10 | somedate | 5 | 11 |col8|col9|col10

```
custid='abc'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#get all invoiceperiod for custid
l = []
cursor.execute("select invoiceperiod from table where custid=? order by invoiceperiod desc", custid)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    l.append(row.invoiceperiod)
print("billingperiod:", l)  

#get other direct mapping fields from DB  
cursor.execute("SELECT col8,col9,col10 FROM table where custid=? and invoiceperiod=(select max(invoiceperiod) from table where custid=?)", custid, custid)

results = []
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

for row in cursor:
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
#    results.append("billingperid", l)
print(results)
```

For given custid ('abc') expected json response should be as below -

```
{
    "accounts": [{
        "custacct": 101,
        "invoiceperiods": ["20190801", "20190701","20190601"],
        "currentinvoicePeriod": "20190801", 
        "custacctsummary":{
            "amtdue":12,
            "duedate":"somedate",
            "charges":2,
            "balance":10
            },
        "col8":value1,
        "col9":value2,
        "col10":value3
        }]
}
```

1] How to construct "custacctsummary" json object and append to json response
2] prepare list of all invoiceperiod for given custid/custacct and append to main json response
3] get value for other attributes for current/latest invoiceperiod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already produces a list of `str`

```python
print("billingperiod:", l)
# billingperiod: ['20190801', '20190701', '20190601']
```

and a list containing a single `dict`

```python
print(results)
# [{'col8': 'value1', 'col9': 'value2', 'col10': 'value3'}]
```

If you change

```python
results = []
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

for row in cursor:
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
#    results.append("billingperid", l)
print(results)
```

to ...

```python
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

row = cursor.fetchone()
results = dict(zip(columns, row))
print(results)
# {'col8': 'value1', 'col9': 'value2', 'col10': 'value3'}
```

... insert the `l` list into the `results` dict and then dump to a JSON string you'll get

```python
results['invoiceperiods'] = l
j = json.dumps(results, indent=4);
print(j)
# {
#     "col8": "value1",
#     "col9": "value2",
#     "col10": "value3",
#     "invoiceperiods": [
#         "20190801",
#         "20190701",
#         "20190601"
#     ]
# }
```

You can use similar logic to build out the rest of your JSON requirements.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, this gave the direction. When I'm trying to build the json in format below (for e.g custid 'abc' having multiple accounts -101,102). So expected json output as:    {   
  accounts:[   
   { }, //json response for acct 101 as shown above 
   { } // json response for acct 102 as shown above
   ]  
 }  Error I'm getting : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: This is what I have in my code to build list of dictionary (under the label accounts: [] )

`dicList = []
dicList.append(results)
dicList['accounts'] = dicList
print(dicList)
j = json.dumps(dicList, indent=4)
print(j) `